# Trying to delete from multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have 4 tables in our application:

- User
- usession
- upklist
- projshare

The last three tables contain a field called `session_id`.

In the code below, the section in parenthesis works to get all `session_id` values from `usession` table for user "awpeople".

The problem is how do I read this result set into an array and delete from all three tables where `session_id` is in the array results.

Code:

```
DELETE FROM usession, 
            upklist, 
            projshar 
WHERE  session_id = (SELECT session_id 
                     FROM   usession 
                     WHERE  delete_session_id IS NULL 
                            AND user_id = (SELECT user_id 
                                           FROM   users 
                                           WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(USER_NAME, 
                                                  'awpeople', 'i')));
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Your mention of reading the results into an array sounds like an attempted solution rather than the actual problem. If you need to delete from 3 tables, you just need to run 3 delete statements.

Comment: You can only delete from a single table at any given time - there's on way to delete from multiple tables at once

Comment: Added `oracle` tag because of the `regexp_like`

Answer (score 6):

`delete` can only handle one table at a time, so you'd need three statements:

```
DELETE FROM upklist 
WHERE  session_id = (SELECT session_id 
                     FROM   usession 
                     WHERE  delete_session_id IS NULL 
                            AND user_id = (SELECT user_id 
                                           FROM   users 
                                           WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(USER_NAME, 
                                                  'awpeople', 'i'))); 

DELETE FROM projshar 
WHERE  session_id = (SELECT session_id 
                     FROM   usession 
                     WHERE  delete_session_id IS NULL 
                            AND user_id = (SELECT user_id 
                                           FROM   users 
                                           WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(USER_NAME, 
                                                  'awpeople', 'i'))); 

DELETE FROM usession 
WHERE  session_id = (SELECT session_id 
                     FROM   usession 
                     WHERE  delete_session_id IS NULL 
                            AND user_id = (SELECT user_id 
                                           FROM   users 
                                           WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(USER_NAME, 
                                                  'awpeople', 'i')));
```

Note that since the inner query relies on `usersession`, you should delete from it **last**.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that you can delete from multiple tables at the same time.  See also: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/delete.html

Comment: @diadyne That page is part of the Oracle MySQL documentation. Oracle database's [`delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505), which OP asks about, does not support multiple table expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If usession has a unique or primary key on session_id, and the other tables have foreign key relationships to it, then you can just delete the row from usession and have the database cascade it to the child tables.

Comment: I have done this in MySQL, do you know if it will work the same way in Oracle?

Comment: Yes: it's pretty much a standard RDBMS feature to cascade deletes on a foreign key

Answer (score -3):

Multiple-table syntax:

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]

Or:

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
USING table_references
[WHERE where_condition]

This comes from Oracle's [MySQL 5.1 DELETE documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150302044420/http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/delete.html).

Comment: The link (it leads to error 404 now) appear to be for MySQL, while the question is about Oracle DB.