# deleting from two tables in single script in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables `xx_1 , xx_2, xx_3`  such that :

xx_1

```
id   obj_version_num     location
1      x                  ubudu
2      x                  bali
3      x                  india
```

xx_2

```
id   name          grade
1    abc           band 1 
2    xyz           band 2 
3    gdgd          band 3
```

xx_3 has :

```
  Name   details    col1          p_id
     abc    A         HDHD        10
     xyz    B         HDHD        20
     gdgd   C         HDHD        30  
     smith  D         HDHD        40
```

I want to delete data from xx_1 and xx_2 if the name is smith in xx_3 
Currently i am doing :

```
delete from xx_1 
where id in (select distinct id from xx_2 t ,xx_3 k
where t.name=k.name
    and k.name ='Smith')

and then 
delete from xx_2 
where name ='Smith'
```

Is there anyway i can delete data from both these table together ? without creating two separate scripts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to delete from multiple tables using SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089695/trying-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-sql)

Comment: You need two statements there is no way around that. But of course they can be stored in a single script.

Comment: If this is something you will be doing regularly perhaps defined your foreign keys and use "ON DELETE CASCADE" to do your single statement deletes.

Comment: @JNevill - yes i will execute thsi package regularly

Comment: The tables mentioned here doesnot actually qualifiy for foreign key relation. Table XX_3 has no ID but only name and name you cannot make it a primary key in real scenario

Comment: @XING - it has another primary key. i have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to delete from many tables with a single statement, but the better question is why do you need to delete from all tables at the same time? It sounds to me like you don't fully understand how transactions work in Oracle.

Lets say you login and delete a row from table 1, but do not commit. As far as all other sessions are concerned, that row has not been deleted. If you open another connection and query for the row, it will still be there.

Then you delete from tables 2, 3 and then 4 in turn. You still have not committed the transaction, so all other sessions on the database can still see the deleted rows.

Then you commit.

All at the same time, the other sessions will no longer see the rows you deleted from the 4 tables, even though you did the deletes in 4 separate statements.

EDIT after edit in question:

You can define the foreign keys on the 3 child tables to "`ON DELETE CASCADE`". Then when you delete from the parent table, all associated rows from the 3 child tables are also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete from multiple tables in a single statement, primary key or not.

Comment: You can if you have defined foreign key relationships and use `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Or you could define a trigger if you hate the people that you work with.

Comment: in that scenario you can, but his question was specific to a statement.